# ansible does not read in variables when connected to another host

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which reads in a list of variables:

```
vars_files:
  - vars/myvariables.yml

 tasks:
  - name: Debug Variable List
    debug:
      msg: "An item: {{item}}"
    with_list: "{{ myvariables }}"
```

This prints out the list of "myvariables" from a file variables.yml, which contains:

```
---
myvariables:
  - variable1
  - variable2
```

I get the following as expected.

```
"msg": "An item: variable1"
"msg": "An item: variable2"
```

However, when I connect to another host, and run the same Debug statement, it throws an error:

```
vars_files:
  - vars/myvariables.yml

 tasks:
  - name: Configure instance(s)
    hosts: launched
    become: True
    remote_user: ubuntu
    port: 22
    gather_facts: False
    tasks:
      - name: Wait for SSH to come up
        delegate_to: ***
        remote_user: ubuntu
        connection: ssh
        register: item
      - name: Debug Variable List
        debug:
          msg: "An item: {{item}}"
        with_list: "{{ myvariables }}"
```

OUTPUT:

```
 "msg": "'myvariables' is undefined"
```

How do I define the variables file when connecting to another host that is not localhost?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Vladimir Botka thanks.  I've added the extra tasks.  I expected this could be a solution on how to pass the variables file to the host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "*hosts: launched*" you started new playbook. Put the *vars_files:* into the scope of this playbook (see below).

```
   - name: Configure instance(s)
     hosts: launched
     become: True
     remote_user: ubuntu
     port: 22
     gather_facts: False
     vars_files:
       - vars/myvariables.yml
     tasks:
```

Review the [Scoping variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables).

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue.  As hosts:launched starts a new playbook, is this the best practice approach when connecting to a host?

Comment: Yes. A playbook starts with connecting a host. Try "*ansible-playbook -vvvvv ...*" and see the workflow.